# PyQt/PySide: Generate Button based on JSon Object

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I want to make a button generator with 4 button each horizontal layout based on how many items in a json. The reasons: the Main UI has code repetition and I want it to able to work with any json templates. Before, I already make the UI Manually:
[Main Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw6rp.png)

It has maximum of 4 button each `QHBoxLayout`. The codes really repetitive:

```
    def content_submit():
        if controllers['current_products'].get('content') is not None:
            controllers['current_products']['content'] += 1
        else:
            controllers['current_products']['content'] = 1
            
        content_label.setText(str(controllers['current_products']['content']))
        controllers['current_prices'] += 4000
        moneys_label.setText(f'Total Moneys: {controllers["current_prices"]}')

    content_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    content_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
    content_button = QPushButton()
    content_label = QLabel()
    content_button.setFixedSize(100, 100)
    content_button.setIcon(QIcon('content.jpg'))
    content_button.setIconSize(QSize(110, 110))
    content_button.clicked.connect(content_submit)
    content_layout.addWidget(content_button, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    content_layout.addWidget(content_label, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

    '''Horizontal Layout Maximum of 4 Button'''
    section_layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
    section_layout1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
    section_layout1.addLayout(content_layout)

    '''Final Layout that Wraps all the Horizontal Layout'''
    section_wrapper = QVBoxLayout()
    section_wrapper.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
    section_label = QLabel('Section')
    section_wrapper.addWidget(section_label)
    section_wrapper.addLayout(section_layout1)

    '''Add Wrappers to Main QWidget()'''
    all_wrappers_layout.addLayout(section_wrapper)
```

The codes is taken from a large scope that contains exactly snippets above, over and over. I have tried the following:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import json
import datetime
from jsonmerge import merge, Merger
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, QScrollArea
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

location = f"./{str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d'))}.json"

class MainWindow(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.wrappers = QVBoxLayout()

        with open('./bin/properties.json') as file:
            json_content = json.load(file)

        for element in list(json_content):
            self.layout_num = 0
            self.products_num = 1
            while not self.products_num == len(json_content[element]):
                self.product_layout = QHBoxLayout()
                self.product_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
                for _ in range(4):
                    self.btn_layout = QVBoxLayout()
                    self.btn_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
                    self.btn = QPushButton(self)
                    self.btn.setFixedSize(100, 100)
                    self.btn.setIcon(QIcon(json_content[element][self.products_num - 1]['icons']))
                    self.btn.setIconSize(QSize(110, 110))
                    self.texti = json_content[element][self.products_num - 1]['products']
                    self.btn.clicked.connect(self.templates)
                    self.btn_label = QLabel()
                    self.btn_layout.addWidget(self.btn_label, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
                    self.btn_layout.addWidget(self.btn, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
                    self.product_layout.addLayout(self.btn_layout)
                    if not self.products_num == len(json_content[element]):
                        self.products_num += 1
                self.wrappers.addLayout(self.product_layout)
                self.layout_num += 1
        self.setLayout(self.wrappers)

    def templates(self):
        if controllers['current_products'].get(self.texti) is not None:
            controllers['current_products'][self.texti] += 1
        else:
            controllers['current_products'][self.texti] = 1
        print(controllers)

def global_var():
    global controllers
    controllers = {'current_products': {}, 'current_prices': 0, 'customer_moneys': 0, 'current_expenses': 0, 'current_reasons': ''}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.path.isfile(location) is False:
        with open(location, 'w') as f:
            f.write('{}')
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
    global_var()

    app = QApplication()
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    app.exec()
```

The only problem from above is that: it adds the same item to `controllers` despite being different button with different icons. I expect that: `__templates__` is being used by all buttons, thus: only the last item inside the json that being added to `controllers` by the `__templates__`:
[Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLRio.png)

My expectation is: the `__templates__` would have different properties depends on the items. In other words: each button will add new item to `controllers['products']` via `__templates__`

Here is my JSon Config:

```
{
    "section":
    [
        {
            "products": "product_name",
            "categories": "product_category",
            "icons": "img/section1/product1.jpg",
            "prices": 1
        }
    ],
    "section2":
    [
        {
            "products": "product_name",
            "categories": "product_category",
            "icons": "img/section2/product1.jpg",
            "prices": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

[Generated Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jelx.png)

Comment: First of all, ***NEVER*** use `exec` or `eval`, nor `locals` (unless you **really** know what you're doing and why). Then, trying to do that to set local variables is completely wrong other than pointless. Just use generic variables and add the widgets and layouts to `wrappers`. Please take your time and revise the code considering the above, as nobody will help you with code that uses `exec` for the wrong reasons (mostly because it probably is the cause of the issue), then [edit] the question with the updated code if it still doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I have revised the code in the same structure, also ends with the same result. It is either ```_templates_``` or ```texti``` variable that keeps updated until last iteration. If there's a way to pass ```texti``` to ```_templates_``` inside ```clicked.connect()```, I would very happy to try it: as doing ```clicked.connect(self.templates(variable)``` completely fires up ```_templates_``` upon json iteration. @musicamante

Comment: That's because you're overwriting instance attributes at each iteration, which is completely pointless: just use variables as already written before, and use a lambda for that connection: `btn.clicked.connect(lambda _, texti=texti: self.templates(texti))` (note that there are **two** arguments for the lambda, with the first positional and the second keyworded, and that's mandatory due to the signal signature and in order to make that lambda work). I'd suggest you to look more into classes, instances and attributes, including the meaning of `self` in Python. Also, don't use `global`.

Comment: `lambda` complaints about the first argument being missing. I admit lambda is new to me. I have tried lambda with no argument ```lambda : templates(texti)``` with templates function being local. I use `global_var` is to make it easy to reset and stores value, as it's also being used outside class. `self` in other hand will inherit `QWidget` as a parents. @musicamante

Comment: how can i add first argument `lambda _` as a signal `True / False`? I tried `lambda texti=texti: self.templates(texti)` still result in the same behavior.

Comment: Using a local function is pointless, you'd be having the same issue. Try with `lambda *args, texti=texti:`; for a case like this, you could probably use partials. Then, do some research about lambdas (they're quite important, you should not ignore them), scope and closures. And I understand your reason behind global, but it's still not good to use it. Besides, it's a dict, just call `clear()`. Finally `self` does not "inherit" anything, and it's not "a parent": it's a reference to the instance, inheritance and kinship are very different things; you should be more careful about terminology.

Comment: Thank you, it is now working as intended. Please post your solution as answer, so I could accept them. It does solve `__templates__` problems. @musicamante